# addClass if at least one checkbox input is "checked", removeClass if none are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, input, addclass, removeclass

I'm currently trying to run a jQuery command based on whether or not checkbox inputs in a list (at least 1, minimum) are checked. Essentially, I'm making another element look active if any checkbox is checked, but want that active state/class to go away if 0 checkboxes are checked.

Here's my current jQuery:

```
$('#data.backup input.backup').change(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#sticky-button.backup').addClass("active");
  } else {
  $('#sticky-button.backup').removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

While the initial if statement works one way (adding the active class), the moment I uncheck any of the boxes, it runs the removeClass command. How could I adjust the code so that the else statement only runs when none of the inputs are checked?

Comment: use `toggleClass` when checkbox checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the entire collection instead of just `this`, `is()` will return true if any checkbox is checked

```
var boxes = $('#data.backup input.backup');

boxes.on('change', function () {
  if ( boxes.is(":checked") ) {
      $('#sticky-button.backup').addClass("active");
  } else {
      $('#sticky-button.backup').removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

You could shorten it with toggleClass

```
var boxes = $('#data.backup input.backup');

boxes.on('change', function () {
  $('#sticky-button.backup').toggleClass("active", boxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bqkm8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $allInputs = $('#data.backup input.backup');

$allInputs.change(function () 
{
    if ($allInputs.is(":checked"))
        $('#sticky-button.backup').addClass("active");

    else
        $('#sticky-button.backup').removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggeClass` and check the length of the `checked` checkboxes.

```
$("#data.backup input.backup").change(function()
{
    $("#sticky-button.backup").toggleClass("active", $("input.backup:checked").length > 0);
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fuR5P/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate over all the boxes when one was unchecked (on change) and see if any were still checked, you can do this using jQuery's provided $.each function:

```
$('#data.backup input.backup').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#sticky-button.backup').addClass("active");
    } else {
        var areAnyChecked = false;

        $('#data.backup input.backup').each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
                areAnyChecked = true;
            });
        });

        if(areAnyChecked != true) {
            $('#sticky-button.backup').removeClass("active");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#data.backup input.backup').change(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#sticky-button.backup').addClass("active");
  } else {
      var flag=0;
      $('#data.backup input.backup').each(function(){
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
              $('#sticky-button.backup').addClass("active");
            flag=1;             
          }
          if(flag == 0){
              $('#sticky-button.backup').removeClass("active");
          }
      });
  }
});
```